# Error: /bin/sh: java: not found with @openapitools

Tags: angular, dockerfile, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I'm trying to run an Angular app container with this docker file:

```
# stage 1
FROM node:alpine AS my-app-build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli -g
RUN npm run build

# stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=my-app-build /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

I need openapitools to generate my client api but I get this error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/main.js:636
                error ? reject(new Error(stderr)) : resolve(stdout);
                               ^

Error: /bin/sh: java: not found

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/main.js:636:32
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1062:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:448:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12)

Node.js v17.3.1
Error response from daemon: The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Why do I need java?
Do I have to install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to install java, or use another openapi generator.

For a angular project I use [ng-openapi-gen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-openapi-gen). This does not need it, and there are probably others.